# Datatables responsive doesn't apply to dynamically added row

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a table of data with the Datatables responsive extension. When the table is downsized the columns from right gets hidden as expected. But if I dynamically add another row of data the new row doesn't get the hidden columns.

I tried binding the table as below:

```
var table = $('.mytable').DataTable({ responsive: true });
```

Then after dynamically appending a data row to the table, I tried these commands to reinitialize the responsiveness, as suggested in the documentation (https://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc%28%29):

```
table.columns.adjust();
table.responsive.recalc();
```

I have also tried the `responsive.rebuild()`-function without luck. Anyone knows how to sort this?

**EDIT, here is a simplified description of how rows are appended**

```
function step_data(step_id, nextstep)
    {
        var data = '<tr id="row_' + step_id + '"><td>' + nextstep + '</td><td>(values)</span></td><td>(data)</td><td><button>Button</button></td></tr>';
        return data;
    }
$('#addstep').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post(
           '/control/addstep',
           {'timeline_id':(xxx) }, 
           function(data){
              var row = step_data(data, nextstep);
              $('#sortablearea').append(row);
              nextstep++;
              table.columns.adjust();
              table.responsive.recalc(); // this doesn't have effect
            }
        );
    });
```

What happens is that the added row breaks the mobile layout and all columns are visible in the added row (row 4 was loaded with the page, row 5 is added dynamically):

[image]

Comment: `table.columns.adjust().responsive.recalc()` should work. Show the code that adds a new record to the table.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Edited the question, so this part of the code is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `append()` to append new rows since jQuery DataTables is not aware of this new row and therefore it cannot make it responsive.

Use [`row.add()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29) API method to add a new row. You don't need to call `columns.adjust()` and `responsive.recalc()` afterwards.

For example, use the code below instead of calling `step_data()` and `append()`:

```js
var rowNode = table
   .row.add( [ nextstep, '(values)', '(data)', '<button>Button</button>' ] )
   .draw()
   .node();

$( rowNode )
   .attr( 'id', 'row_' + data )
```

Comment: Great, I converted the code from an existing solution without DataTables, so I didn't think of that DT has its own way of adding rows... Thanks, you saved my afternoon! :)