# How to restart a DataTable created with an append in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an issue at restarting my datatable, when I fill my datatable according a web service results, and it fills correctly but at the moment to make a research by clicking the (Search Button) again the datatable contains the old header and it shows the results but the function does not include the results into the DataTable and it shows 1 to 1 of 1 entries, which is correspondence to old searching.

This is my JavaScript:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/enrollment.asmx/MethodSearch',
                data: "{ 'esiidVal': " + $("#esiID").val() + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#loadingDiv").hide();

                    //$("#data").append("<table id='tbSearch' class='table table-hover display'><thead><tr><th>City</th><th>Zip</th><th>Address</th><th>State</th><th>Location ID</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "'><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/city'>" + data.d.City + "</td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/zip'>" + data.d.Zip + "</td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/adds'>" + data.d.Adds + "</td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/state'>" + data.d.State + "</td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/location'>" + data.d.SNumer + "</td></tr></tbody></table>");
                    $("#db").append("<thead><tr><th>Selection</th><th>City</th><th>Zip</th><th>Address</th><th>State</th><th>ESIID</th><th>Utility</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "'><td><input type='checkbox' name='userinformation' value='#'></td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/city'>" + data.d.City + "</td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/zip'>" + data.d.Zip + "</td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/adds'>" + data.d.Adds + "</td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/state'>" + data.d.State + "</td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/location'>" + data.d.SNumer + "</td><td id='" + data.d.City + data.d.Zip + data.d.Adds + "/utility'>" + data.d.Utility + "</td></tr></tbody>");
                    //var html = "<thead><tr><th>City</th><th>Zip</th><th>Address</th><th>State</th><th>ESIID</th><th>Utility</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
                    $('#db').DataTable();

                    $('#db').after($("checkbox").addClass('checkbox-primary'));


                },
                error: function (e) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(e));
                    $("#divResult").html("Something Wrong.");
                }
            });
```

[image]

I tried destroy(), didn't work, I also tried clean() didn't work. I have weeks facing this issue. Can somebody help me with my issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469536/datatables-responsive-doesnt-apply-to-dynamically-added-row

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

table.draw() should do the trick.  Make the call after appending rows.

Comment: Have you considered ajax sourced tables?  https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html  It seems like an easier way to reload the table.

Comment: I have but the thing is that I have to validate many things right after selecting a row, and pass the parameters from the selected row to another sections of my web.

Comment: Remove the $('#db').DataTable(); from the post.  On success, redraw.

Comment: It showed me this eror '$(...).draw is not a function'

Comment: var table = $("#myTable").DataTable(); and then table.draw();

Comment: Unfortunately it happens the same, it overwrites the results and the filters do not work.

Comment: What do you mean by results?  Are you trying to append result to filtered data?

Comment: It happens the same than the picture I uploaded. It researches fine, but if you can notice on the results it is showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries. But that's not true.

Comment: When you click again the search button it overwrites the results, and it seems the datatable does not work properly

Comment: See the comment above from Luca.  I think you should be appending the rows differently.

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried what Luca said but it didn't work.